What exactly is going on during electron coupling?
Straight to the point: It's hard for me to imagine physically what electrons are doing when they "couple". Is an unpaired electron from one orbital essentially moving to an orbital with another unpaired electron and pairing up with it? Does this have any other meaningful effect on the orbital?
Broader Context
This question is in the context of multiplet splitting. This phenomenon is often exhibited by elements with unpaired valence electrons when performing X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy (XPS). It apparently occurs due to electron coupling:
"When a core electron vacancy is created by photoionization, there can be coupling between the unpaired electron in the core with the unpaired electrons in the outer shell. This can create a number of final states, which will be seen in the photoelectron spectrum as a multi-peak envelope." [1]
This typically results in a set of closely spaced peaks, each one representing a different final state. In the case of Cr2O3, we end up with 5 peaks in the binding energy spectrum of the 2p orbital, so 5 different ways coupling can occur I suppose.
I still poorly understand how multiplet splitting works and hoped I could get closer to understanding if someone could clarify electron coupling. What are the electrons physically doing? Why does this create multiple final states?
[1] http://www.xpsfitting.com/2008/09/multiplet-splitting.html

An electron has (quantised spin) angular momentum and so  its own  magnetic field thus two or more electrons can interact to produce several electronic energy levels. These can be worked out using a  Vector model of the coupling, and is common in spectroscopy not just  with x-rays. See Atkins & Friedman, Molecular Quantum Mechanics'.

It may also help taking into account that when you have unpaired electrons, the interaction between electrons with the same spin function is different that the one with the same spin function. In a UHF calculation you would have that the exchange integrals in the first case are necessary zero, while in the second not. Thus, their is a different correlation between the electron of both kinds of orbitals.

Also consider that the 'coupling' interactions are there all along. Symmetry means that the coupling of the lone valence electron to a filled inner orbital is zero, but remove one of those inner electrons and symmetry no longer applies - the coupling 'appears' yet was there all along.
